# python: concatenating multiple pandas strings within FOR loop

Tags: python

I am working on a Python program that reads spefic .SDF filles from a given directory in a loop and then store some information regarding each file in pandas DF format. There is specific function which accept .SDF file and then return a data file contained one string with all required information about it. In the code below I've tried to apply this function (which works correctly!) on many .SDF filles and then append all linnes in new data file (should contain the same number of lines as a number of processed filles). How this concatenuation of separate DF should be realized correctly within for loop?

```
def load_sdf_file(file, key):
    """
    Reads molecules from an SDF file and store some of its properties as data file
    """
    df = PandasTools.LoadSDF(file)
    df['Source'] = key
    df['LogP']   = df['ROMol'].apply(Chem.Descriptors.MolLogP)
    df['MolWt']  = df['ROMol'].apply(Chem.Descriptors.MolWt)
    df['LipinskyHBA'] = df['ROMol'].apply(Chem.rdMolDescriptors.CalcNumLipinskiHBA)
    df['LipinskyHBD'] = df['ROMol'].apply(Chem.rdMolDescriptors.CalcNumLipinskiHBD)
   
    df = df[['Source','LogP','MolWt','LipinskyHBA','LipinskyHBD']]
    return df


pwd = os.getcwd()
filles='sdf'
results='results'
#set directory to analyse
data = os.path.join(pwd,filles) 


os.chdir(data)
dirlist = [os.path.basename(p) for p in glob.glob(data + '/*.sdf')]
# create a new data file with the same columns as it was in df defined in the function
all = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source','LogP','MolWt','LipinskyHBA','LipinskyHBD'])

for sdf in dirlist:
        try:
                sdf_name=sdf.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ]
                key = f'{sdf_name}'
                df = load_sdf_file(sdf,key)
                print(f'{sdf_name}.sdf has been processed')
                # this does not work!
                all.append(df)
        except:
                print(f'{sdf_name}.sdf has not been processed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and store the dataframes in a list:

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_df = []
for _ in range(10):
    list_of_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'col_a':[1,1,1], 'col_b':[2,2,2]}))
df = pd.concat(list_of_df)
```